# Excel: Data validation of specific numbers with special cell formatting

Tags: excel

I'm just now learning about data validation of cell values in Excel and have discovered a problem that I would like to solve. I have a cell which I only want to allow specific number values. This is no problem since I can just use the data validation for that specific cell. What I can't do is use the "numbers" criteria to have only numbers 10; 20; 30 for example because I can only specify number ranges (larger than, less than, between etc). Instead of using the number range I use the "list" function and simply write 10; 20; 30 and it works.

The problem occurs when I then add a special formatting to that cell. Let's say that I want the format to be one that isn't pre-existing in Excel, that I would like to enter the value "10" but it should display "10 moneys" or something that is grammatically correct. If I only use the custom formatting I can just add " moneys" after the "Standard" that is displayed in the cell format menu (ctrl + 1).

If I do either one this works, but if I add both the list 10; 20; 30, AND the formatting of Standard" moneys" it doesn't work when I use the drop down menu. The reason is because the drop down menu tries to add the value "10 moneys" and the list doesn't recognise this because it expects "10" to be entered. If I change the list to 10 moneys; 20 moneys; 30 moneys, the drop down menu works, but then I can't enter the number "10", "20" or "30" manually because the list expects the entry to be "10 moneys" etc.

Does anyone here have a suggestion on how to solve this?

I know I can just use the first example and tell people that will use this document to manually input the numbers but I want to eliminate the potential errors as far as possible.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions you might have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of values must be in a named range for the custom format to work. You can follow these steps.

1. In another column enter the values 10, 20, and 30 (in cells A1, A2,
   A3 for example).
2. Highlight these cells and Press Ctrl+F3 to bring up the Name Manager
3. Click "New" and enter a name for the new range (e.g. "MyValues")
4. Select the range of cells where you want the data validation to be
5. Select Data > Data Validation, select "List" from the 'Allow' dropdown, and then enter the name range (e.g. `=MyValues`) as the Source
6. With the same range still highlighted, Press Ctrl+1 to add your custom number format (i.e. Select "Custom" from the list of Categories, and then enter General "moneys" in the Type textbox)

Now, whether you enter the values 10,20, or 30 manually into the cell, or select them from the dropdown, you should get the same result ("10 moneys", "20 moneys", or "30 moneys")

Comment: That is the problem, it doesn't. When I do both of these and I enter "10" in the cell it gives me the error that I have entered a value that is not in the list. This is because it reformats 10 as "10 moneys" and the list only contains 10. This is the issue that I'm trying to solve.

Comment: If you select the value from the dropdown, it should work. Is that not working either?

Comment: That is working, but my problem is I want both of these to work :) I can only get either of them to work, and I know that if both doesn't the users will come yelling that there is a bug in the sheet. I agree that it should be fine with using either drop-down or by inputing values but I would like both to work. EDIT: I can use the drop down and the input method if I write "10 moneys" etc in the list, but using that reformats it as a text string, and I want it to still be formatted as a number, if that clarifies anything.

Comment: is your list going to be only 10, 20, 30?

Comment: step 1 or 5 should include "make sure number formats in validation and destination ranges are the same"... @MagneTism do not write `10 moneys` into any cell, always use `10` and change number format

Comment: Thank you for the edit of the answer! This worked out just as I wanted it to, and now the users will not break the system so easy :)